# making a forms dropdown a link?

Tags: html

I created a form and I want the form to behave in a way that when it is filled and submitted it will lead then to a page based on what was selected by them in the dropdown.

```
<div id="type">
   Drop down one:
   <select id="typefield">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you could use few different approaches to solve it. At the moment none of your options has any values assigned, I also see no form. Once you give different value to each option you can manipulate them accordingly, depending on chosen value. Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an `onchange` event to the select field and when the user selects a new value, update the form's `action` attribute to point to the new url.

```
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');

select.onchange=function(e){
    form.setAttribute('action', e.target.value);
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3vbt67j/2/)

Comment: thanks it works, at first i had  issues with it but it eventually worked.

Comment: i  was also wondering if it is possible to add two links to a particular list. this is because, there is a case where i want a small question to pop up before leading them to the page, but the pop up shows while loading the default page.